# URL Rewrite based on trailing slashes in requested url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a dynamic php website which serves content from database. Currently I'm having four PHP files- `index.php` , `a.php` , `b.PHP` , `c.php`. These serves result from the database as par the requested URL. eg.

1. If the requested url `example.com` then `index.php` serves results.
2. If the requested url is `example.com/xyz.html` then `a.php` first exact `xyz` from the url and then serves result for `xyz`. [rewrite `example.com/a.php` to `example.com/xyz.html`]
3. If the requested url is `example.com/x/y.html` then `b.php` first extract `x` and `y` from the requested url and then serves result for `y` page [rewrite `example.com/a.php/b.php` to `example.com/x/y.html`].
4. If the requested url is `example.com/x/y/z.html` the `c.php` first extract `x` , `y` , `z` from the url and then serve result for `z` page (rewrite `example.com/a.php/b.php/c.php` to `example.com/x/y/z.html`).

In short if the requested url is -

`example.com` or `example.com/` - then results will be served by `index.php`

`example.com/anything.html` - then result will be served by `a.php`

`example.com/anything/anything.html` - then result will be served by `b.php`

`example.com/anything/anything/anything.html` - then result will be parsed by `c.php`

So how can i achieve such functionality using URL rewritting ? Please reply with `.htaccess` code for such functionality.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

create a function that will handle your url request,
switch statements or whatever algorithm u want

Comment: @Semi-Friends Thanks ! I need a bit more explaination or htaccess code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!(a|b|c)\.php$)[^/.]+\.php$ /a.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/.]+\.php$ /b.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/.]+\.php$ /c.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Getting "500 Internal Server Error" on all the pages.

Comment: check updated rule and tell me what error do you see in Apache error.log for this

Comment: [Thu Jun 19 13:51:04 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: I've enabled mode_rewrite module and the problem is fixed now. But when i try to request example.com the server serve a.php but i want index.php